Does Tomura Shigaraki with All for One have more quirks than All for One had?
So Tomura Shigaraki got the All for One quirk from All for One. But I dont remember All for One having such a powerful regeneration quirk or any regeneration quirk at all.
Does Tomura Shigaraki with All for One have more quirks than All for One had?
